# Get travel time between two addresses using The Google Maps Distance Matrix API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-native

I am setting up a routine to get travel time between two locations using [The Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start).

Example from their page:

> If between `Washington, DC` and `New York City, NY`, then request should look like this:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key="MY_API_KEY_HERE"

If I call the above in chrome normally like any https call, with my API Key, it works fine. [Result Here](https://s10.postimg.org/lrognt2zd/Screen_Shot_2017-05-08_at_10.45.29_AM.png).

But when I use any other address, I always get **INAVLID_REQUEST** in my application, but works fine in chrome. [Here is a duplicate that has zero comments/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662779/google-distance-matrix-api-error-invalid-request).

[Their Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix):

> INVALID_REQUEST: The provided request was invalid. This is often due to missing required fields. See the "list of supported fields" above.

My usage:

```
export async function getDistance()
{
    // get location of base
    const BaseLocation = "555 E Lafayette St, Detroit, MI 48226";

    // get locations of targets
    const TargetLocation = "21000 W 10 Mile Rd, Southfield, MI 48075";

    // prepare final API call
    let ApiURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?";
    let params = `origins=${BaseLocation}&destinations=${TargetLocation}&key=${GOOGLE_DISTANCES_API_KEY}`;  
    let finalApiURL = `${ApiURL}${encodeURI(params)}`;

    console.log("finalApiURL:\n");
    console.log(finalApiURL);

    // get duration/distance from base to each target
    try {
            let response =  await fetch(ApiURL);
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log("responseJson:\n");
            console.log(responseJson);
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        } 
}
```

and I call it from another file like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    // ..
    getDistance();

}
```

Result in Console (Not working - INVALID_REQUEST):

```
finalApiURL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=555%20E%20Lafayette%20St,%20Detroit,%20MI%2048226&destinations=21000%20W%2010%20Mile%20Rd,%20Southfield,%20MI%2048075&key="Can't Expose My Key On Stack Overflow"

responseJson:

Object {destination_addresses: Array[0], origin_addresses: Array[0], rows: Array[0], status: "INVALID_REQUEST"}
```

If I copy and paste `finalApiURL` and use it in Chrome, it works fine. Results:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "21000 W 10 Mile Rd, Southfield, MI 48075, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "555 E Lafayette St, Detroit, MI 48226, USA" ],
   "rows" : [{
         "elements" : [{
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "28.1 km",
                  "value" : 28073},
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "23 mins",
                  "value" : 1367},
               "status" : "OK"}]}],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What would be the problem? Please and thanks

Comment: Do you also get the same error if you access that URL with `curl` for example? I tried `curl -i $finalApiURL` with my own key and it works for me.

Comment: Sorry I might have misread something (or perhaps it was before your edit... no importance). If you paste that URL to Chromes's address bar and it works, then you don't need to test with `curl` (it's just a command line tool). You have one thing in common with the duplicate: you are accessing the API from a non-browser program, but that should not make a difference. Hmmm...

Comment: @HuguesMoreau Yes sorry I think I added the duplicate part after your comment. That is weird indeed, I edited and added my exact usage, maybe take a look? async/wait has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo, here is the correct line:

```
let response = await fetch(finalApiURL);
```

Not `ApiURL`, this one has no parameters and is therefore invalid, exactly as the doc says ;)

Comment: Hahaha :D I feel just a _little_ dump. Thanks bud !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work . if you does not have await support you can try out this .

```
setTimeout(() => {
      let response = await fetch(finalApiURL);

          });
```